# how to store keyboard key code as a value in var c#

Tags: c#, input, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-events

I would like to store key values into list or dictionary so I can simply change them if needed, when needed.

I am catching the key press like this, now.

```
if (e.Key == Key.D1)
            {
                if ((trackstatus[1].IsReserved == true) && (trackstatus[1].IsReady == true))
                { 
                    (alltimers[0] as stopwatch).SwitchOn();
                    trackstatus[1].IsReady = false;
                }
            }
```

Is there a way I can store that Key.D1 into some var like this and how, because sometimes I have more than 1 track and different Key bindings. Thanks in advance.

```
var something = Key.D1;
if (e.Key == something)
            {
                if ((trackstatus[1].IsReserved == true) && (trackstatus[1].IsReady == true))
                { 
                    (alltimers[0] as stopwatch).SwitchOn();
                    trackstatus[1].IsReady = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: "I have more than 1 track and different Key bindings" ... you really need to be more specific about your requirements. What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: It means that can have up to 6 tracks, and each requires start/stop combo. So this means that for instance track 1: might use Key.D1 for starting and Key.D2 for stopping time. While track 2 might have Key.D3 and Key.D4 respectively as start/stop, and so on...I don't want to write 12 if e.Key == Key.Whatever. I want to map track to stop and start keys, so i need to store this "Key.D1 or Key.D2 or ....." (which is basically number 1 on keyboard) into some sort of variable. So I would only check if e.Key can be found in var/list/dictionary or not. That's it.

Comment: OK, divide and conquer: 1. You could have a Lookup (Maybe Dictionary) Key->Action. 2. A configuration module registers the appropriate action to a key (makes entries to that dictionary). Then all the event handler has to do is lookup the action for whatever key and execute it.

Comment: I didn't know how to store Key.D1 into var. It should be used like this. Key somekey = Key.D1. This way somekey is then binded to Key.D1. Now I can check somekey agains event.Key. Now I will put all the combos in dictionary. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I will create a list, which will hold Dictionary<Key, Key>. So first track will have their combo, in list[0], second track in list[1], etc ... thanks for ideas m8.

Comment: Wait, what? Why `Dictionary<Key,Key>` ?? I was thinking of `Dictionary<Key, Action>` then you can simply add for example Key.D1 as Key and some [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) as Value. The Action will implement what has to be done. So the eventhandler is left with `dic[e.Key].Invoke()`